# Gitignore not working on new rep

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitignore

I'm using win10 ,and sublime 3.

My .gitignore looks like:

```
node_modules/
```

Also a note, when I create new gitignore and try to save it as ".gitignore" , the filename is empty so I have to manually change it to ".gitignore".

I want to create new git repo from an already existing project. (I've created a new repo on bitbucket).

So I do got o my project folder and do the following:

```
git init 

git remote add origin https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/website-materialdesign.git

git add .
```

And I can see that it isn't ignoring node_modules cause I can see him throw warnings that are from node_modules.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which char encoding do you use for the file? I suspect it could have BOM

Comment: @kan If I run view.encoding(); In sublime I get back 'Undefined'.

Comment: I saved it as UTF-8 , but node_modules still doesn't get ignored cause when I do "git add . " I get a lot of output like this "The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/utils-merge/index.js.
"

Comment: There are two encodings for a file "UTF-8 with BOM" and "UTF-8 without BOM". Try to put an empty line at the beginning of the file, so that your folder name will appear on the second line.

Comment: I added new on at the beginning of the file, same results. My encoding is UTF-8 without BOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that on win10 when you save file with extension "All files" with a filename ".gitignore" it will create a file with a seemingly empty file name.

Which is fine cause that's the only way I managed to get my gitignore file to work.